# What should my internal representation of an object in the category of small categories be?

Tags: category-theory

What exactly should I think of a category as? The usual definition of a category as a collection of objects + some morphisms between these objects seems a little vague to me.

Say that we have $\textbf{Set}$, the category of sets and functions and a category that I made up $\textbf{Set}_{id}$ which is the category where objects are sets and the morphisms are only the identity morphisms. Is the one I made up a real category and if so, how is it related to $\textbf{Set}$?

Now let's consider the category $\textbf{2}$ where there are two objects $A$ and $B$, their identity morphisms, and a single morphism $f : A \to B$. What does this $f$ morphism do to the elements of $A$?

Comment: What is imprecise about the "usual definition" of a category?

Comment: It might just be morphisms that's throwing me off. How can we tell if two morphisms are equal? Are we supposed to look explicitly at what the morphisms do on elements of their domain?

Comment: In an abstract category, morphisms don't "do" anything, they are just labels on the edges of a graph whose vertices are the objects. The composition operation on edges is part of the structure of the category. Think of it like the multiplication table of a group.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks, I think this is where my misunderstanding came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morphisms in categories don't do anything to elements of anything, in general. In your category $A$ might be Richard Nixon, $B$ the complex numbers, and $f$ my coffee mug. You introduce identity arrows, define a composition in the only possible way and you have a category. $f$ need not be a function or anything like a function.

The problem here may be less with the definition of a category and more with your not having worked through enough examples. You also may not have seen a precise definition of a category, so make sure to look one up. Do you know how every group becomes a category? Every partially ordered set? You should also check yourself whether your proposed category of sets and identity morphisms is actually a category. There is a short list of axioms that are easy to verify. If you know how to prove a set with a given operation is a group, you should have no trouble with this.

Comment: By the definition of category, we only need identity morphisms for any given collection of objects to be a category, so I've defined a category. If we can't think of morphisms as maps on the elements, then how can we say that two morphisms are equal? How should i picture a morphism in my head?

Comment: @user514088 How do you picture an element of an abstract group in your head? For less of a non-answer, I picture a morphism in an arbitrary category as a literal arrow.

Comment: @user514088 Typically, equality is defined globally and logically. That is, we're working in something like first-order logic with equality. To this end, asking about equality is always possible between any two things we can talk about. You could take a different approach where each hom-set is equipped with a notion of equality in a way compatible with the categorical structure, but this could be a fairly arbitrary relation between elements that don't have to be mappings, and even if they were the provided notion equality could be different from extensional equality.

Comment: @user514088 To combine a couple of Kevin Carlson's points, a specific example is the group of integers. This gives you category with one object whose value is irrelevant, and whose morphisms are integers. I presume you have no issue with equality of integers even though they aren't mappings. As suggested by Kevin Carlson, you should completely and as formally as you can work through this example (and the other Kevin Carlson suggested). Similarly later for functors and natural transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\textbf{Set}_{id}$ is, in fact, a category, and it is the smallest subcategory of $\textbf{Set}$ that share its objects.

To your second point, why does it have to do anything? Look at the elements of sets in usual mathematics: do they necessarily have an internal structure? No, because if we want to add abstraction to our study, it is necessary not to assume structure from this elements.

The same applies to a morphism: it does not have to do anything; and $A$ does not need to have internal structure either. Just think of $A$ and $B$ as points and $F$ as literally an arrow connecting $A$ to $B$, in this order: it is your category, or at least one interpretation of it, and $f$ does not affect the elements of $A$, which in turn does not have elements!